# Applying a bootstrap theme to Laravel Vite Inertia React Bootstrap project

Tags: reactjs, laravel, bootstrap-5, vite, inertiajs

I am rebuilding a quite large Laravel project but this time using Inertia. I am a little bit lost though. I have an app.scss file that imports bootstrap and a bootstrap theme like this:
`@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'; @import './theme/src/scss/theme.scss';`

In my app.tsx I am then importing it like this:
`import "../css/app.scss";`

Before, when I only imported bootstrap everything seemed to be working fine. But after I tried to add the theme I get a vite compiler error saying "Undefined mixin". It seems like the theme I am using isn't getting the bootstrap core mixins properly. I am unsure how to debug this. How do I make sure that my theme files are pointing to my bootstrap core files?

I hope this question makes sense.

I have set up a Vite alias for bootstrap like this:

`alias: { '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'), }`
which seems to have been successful as it let's me apply bootstrap classes on my html. I know tailwind might be easier to get going with Laravel but in my case there is already a whole bunch of code written in bootstrap and I won't have the time to rewrite it.